# How to make two alembic Mesh Sequence Caches working together

Tags: animation, mesh, modifiers, alembic

I would like to play two .abc sequences in one scene. However, they seem to be hating each other, so after importing second sequence, the first one stops playing. I've noticed that the object path is the same for both of them, so I think that might be the problem. Is there a way to change it somehow (rename mesh_shape to something that works)? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: I am using 2.79.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work. Would you care to [write a detailed bug report](https://developer.blender.org/) with some minimal Alembic files that show this problem?

Answer (score 1):

*Blender Sushi Guy* here, I encountered the exact same situation today. And I think I have a solution that is using Sverchok nodes, but easily translateable into **Drivers** or **Python** code solution. I think Dr. Sybren can help :)

[image]

So, I have multiple alembic cace file, each for 1000 frames. I broken down the Alembic sequence into multiple caches because 10000 frames == keeps crashing Blender.

Anyhow, just like what you are trying to do, you want to "mix" the Alembic cache together, using Modifier stacks.

Ideally, there should be a mechanism in Blender allowing to do this. Maybe Blender devs are still working on it(?).

For now, I am using this "simple trick" that is basically triggering the "show_viewport" ON and OFF as needed.

I have 2 caches here, cache A (frame 1-1000) and cache B (frame 1001-2000). You can have more.

Both has "Override Frame" turned on. So we will be controlling the frame using "Time Frame". That part is taken care of.

But as you mentioned, once you stack multiple cache, the second will completely override the previous.

However if you control the "show_viewport" and trigger ON and OFF at the right time (in this case I am using nodes logic to check frame number, **if frame number is bigger than > 1000**, then 2nd cache SHOULD take over and continue the cache. Otherwise, it should run the 1st cache first.

Let say we have 3,4,5 cache, we can use similar logic.

I test a quick OpenGL render and seems like my cache A and B mixed together into the same mesh.

I wonder what Blender Devs working on Alembic can say about this.

But that is one solution.

Perhaps "Use Modifier During Render" (the camera icon) also needs to be triggered.

[image: animation with timeline]

The easiest is to use Drivers, for this. In my case, I am relying on nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is not a solution for two mesh sequences running at the SAME TIME. Do you have any idea how to run two alembic casches simultaneously without overriding each other? The thing is, I can not animate both mesh and foam imported from Realflow and that just sucks :(

Comment: Apparently, Blender 2.79b works with multiple mesh caches just fine!!! 2.79 (without "b") was the problem. Thanks for your effort!